How to fetch google form response with required email in Google App Script
As the title, I got some problem when trying to automate response google forms type collect submitter data but I am not the form's owner
Here is the form:
Sample Form
Below is my scratch code in GAS:
function submitToGoogleFormWithEmail() {
    var formUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdBdRIYCAaxp2FI4n0rVZywcz0Br7n2DOBOIcWSLHP9B67ikA/formResponse";
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    Logger.log(token);

    var payload = {
        "entry.1507679348": "lucasdo",
        "entry.21751216": "dnd",
        "entry.528181198": "appscript",
        "emailAddress": email
    };

    var options = {
        'method': 'post',
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        'payload': payload,
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formUrl, options);
    Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
}

When I test the code, it showed error code 401 in console log of app script.
Console Log Screenshot
I tried with browser console fetching, it worked if I logged in before and go to below url:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdBdRIYCAaxp2FI4n0rVZywcz0Br7n2DOBOIcWSLHP9B67ikA/formResponse?entry.1507679348=lucasdo&entry.21751216=dnd&entry.528181198=appscript&emailAddress=my_email@gmail.com
Similar thread but not helpful so much: How to auto submitting in require sign-in google form from google apps script
Does anyone have the solution for this case?

Welcome to StackOverflow! May I ask if you want to get all the emails of the people who responded to the form?

Why are you using an HTTP Post request instead of the Forms Service?

This might help Post request failed with error code 400 when submitting Google form

It appears that the Form Settings for "Responses">"Collect email addresses" has been set to Verified. This required two things for the respondent: 1) they are required to login to Google and 2) they are required to physically check the box with the text " Record <> as the email to be included with my response. This email address is subsequently catted and passed to a linked spreadsheet BUT when one looks at the "items" in the Form, the "Email address" is not an accessible item. In short, you are trying to update a field that doesn't exist.

@JatsPPG: I am not the form owner, I just want to submit to another user's form.

@Wicket: Because I am not the form owner, I don't have permission to that form so I don't think Form Service can be used here. But I will try you suggested link.

@Tedinoz: I can fetch and submit it via browser console (maybe cookies or st were automatically added in header), but cannot do it in Google App Script

But it does not work with GAS because of authorization I beg to differ. It does not work with apps script because there is no syntax to update that particular field. It requires manual input.

I can fetch via browser console with url below Can you? The email field is a check box not an email address; the value of the email field is already populated because when you open the browser you are getting the email address for the logged in user.

@Tedinoz: you can try my above url after replacing "my_email" with you real gmail then enter it to address bar, it will show success response

@Tedinoz: I reverse the Borang extension and see that they can submit with required sign-in option in google form.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwtJXyfgOKk&list=PLeOkJoio8AuGxZxfwHEYmHGS3hcPUBMpx&index=8

I tried with browser console fetching it worked if I logged in before and went to the below url: -  It seems that you need an Account for you to submit a response because the form settings are requiring the respondents to sign in to Google for verification. If you really wish to submit a response for others using Google App Script, it's not possible unless, you are the owner of the Google Form.

I can't offer a definitive answer about using Google Apps Script server-side code to post a response to a Google Form owned by someone else that is set to collect the form respondent's email address automatically, but I can mention a couple of things.
Regarding your attempts to use the web browser console and extensions, these options are not directly comparable with using Google Apps Script's FetchUrlApp.fetch, first because this method runs on Google's servers while the mentioned options run on the user's device. Second, the Google Apps Script user cannot control all the possibilities for making HTTP requests due to limitations set by Google, i.e., the user-agent can't be customized. For details, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch.
In addition to Google Apps Script, other cloud services, such as https://www.postman.com, can handle HTTP requests. Some of them allow the user to play with more options.
